# Is there a way to refactor two methods, one that calls an awaited method, and one that calls a normal one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, functional-programming, async-await, func

I'm working on building a caching service for a website, and I want to provide a public interface that can take a `Func<TKey,TValue>` or `Func<TKey,Task<TValue>>` method a that can be called by the service for a cache miss.

I'm ending up duplicating codes in handling these two delegate types. Is there a way to consolidate? I'm especially concerned that 'Func' methods are not thread safe, and are not suitable for wrapping in a 'Task.Run'.

Here's my code:

```cs
public interface ICacheServiceEngine
{
    Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetValueAsync<TValue>(string key);
    Task<CacheResult<TValue>> 
        TryGetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, Func<TKey,string> keyFunc);
    Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<string, TValue> valueSourceFunc);
    Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, 
        Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, TValue> valueSourceFunc);
    Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<string, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync);
    Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, 
        Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync);
}

public interface ICacheServiceDataAccessor
{
    Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetAsync<TValue>(string key);
    Task PutAsync<TValue>(string key , TValue result);
}


public class CacheServiceEngine : ICacheServiceEngine
{
    private ICacheServiceDataAccessor cacheDataAccessor;


    public CacheServiceEngine(ICacheServiceDataAccessor cacheDataAccessor)
    {   
        // add guard
        this.cacheDataAccessor = cacheDataAccessor;
    }


    public async Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetValueAsync<TValue>(string key)
    {
        return await this.cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(key);
    }

    public async Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, 
        Func<TKey,string> keyFunc)
    {
        string keyString = keyFunc(key);
        return await this.cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(keyString);
    }   

    public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<string, TValue> valueSourceFunc)
    {
        return await this.InnerGetValueAsync(key, () => valueSourceFunc(key));
    }

    public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, 
        Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, TValue> valueSourceFunc)
    {
        string keyString = keyFunc(key);
        return await this.InnerGetValueAsync(keyString, () => valueSourceFunc(key));
    }

    public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<string, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync)
    {
        return await this.InnerGetValueAsync(key, () => valueSourceFuncAsync(key));
    }

    public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, 
        Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync)
    {
        string keyString = keyFunc(key);
        return await this.InnerGetValueAsync(keyString, 
            () => valueSourceFuncAsync(key));
    }


    // the two private methods are very close to each other
    // can I pull out the similarities, if I assume that 'valueSourceFunc'
    // is not thread-safe?
    private async Task<TValue> InnerGetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<TValue> valueSourceFunc)
    {
        TValue value;
        CacheResult<TValue> cacheResult = 
            await this.cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(key);

        if (cacheResult.InCache)
        {
            value  = cacheResult.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            // this call is normal (synchronous)
            value = valueSourceFunc();
            await this.cacheDataAccessor.PutAsync(key, value);
        }
        return value;   
    }

    private async Task<TValue> InnerGetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
        Func<Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync)
    {
        TValue value;
        CacheResult<TValue> cacheResult = 
            await this.cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(key);

        if (cacheResult.InCache)
        {
            value  = cacheResult.Value;
        }
        else 
        {
            // this call has to be awaited
            value = await valueSourceFuncAsync();
            await this.cacheDataAccessor.PutAsync(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should reconsider your `ICacheServiceDataAccessor`. It is entirely possible that you may calculate values unnecessarily when a key is not in the cache. I would suggest something like this:

```
public interface ICacheServiceDataAccessor
{
  Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetAsync<TValue>(string key);
  Task<CacheResult<TValue>> GetOrPutAsync<TValue>(string key, Func<Task<TValue>> result);
}
```

But - ignoring that issue for the moment - there is a way to treat a synchronous call as an asynchronous call: `Task.FromResult`.

```
public Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetValueAsync<TValue>(string key)
{
    return cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(key);
}

public Task<CacheResult<TValue>> TryGetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, 
    Func<TKey, string> keyFunc)
{
    string keyString = keyFunc(key);
    return cacheDataAccessor.TryGetAsync<TValue>(keyString);
}   

public Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
    Func<string, TValue> valueSourceFunc)
{
    return InnerGetValueAsync(key, () => Task.FromResult(valueSourceFunc(key)));
}

public Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey,TValue>(TKey key, 
    Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, TValue> valueSourceFunc)
{
    string keyString = keyFunc(key);
    return InnerGetValueAsync(keyString, () => Task.FromResult(valueSourceFunc(key)));
}

public Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string key, 
    Func<string, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync)
{
    return InnerGetValueAsync(key, () => valueSourceFuncAsync(key));
}

public async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, 
    Func<TKey,string> keyFunc, Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueSourceFuncAsync)
{
    string keyString = keyFunc(key);
    return InnerGetValueAsync(keyString, () => valueSourceFuncAsync(key));
}
```

As a final design note, I would consider having only the most generic of these be an actual member of `ICacheServiceEngine`. Since the others are actually just overloads for that method (and will always have the same implementation regardless of the derived class), they could be defined as extension methods on `ICacheServiceEngine`.